# When Executing Snap Tool, Automatically select feature when Multiple found

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, snapping

I currently have 50,000+ points that have to be snapped to lines in my fiber network. Issue is I do not have the time (or patience) to sit here and make the selection every time there are multiple objects within a meter. Is there a way to have it automatically select a feature and not interrupt the process by bringing up the dialog? 
Possibly just select the closest feature and/or just select arbitrarily in the case of duplicate lines? I do not care at the moment if the incorrect line is selected for a small percentage, these will be QC'd at a later date.

[image]

Comment: My snap does it automatically, what ArcGIS version are you using?

Comment: ArcMap 10.3.1, to be specific the tool I'm using for this is https://i.imgur.com/6YT7Em7.png

Comment: Same version, same tool. Strange

Comment: are these multiple features the **exact** same distance from the feature you want to snap?

Comment: it is possible that some are, but most aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was, I have a custom Extension that was filling in the CableGUID that was causing this dialog to come up.